# jquery, add/remove class when window width changes

Tags: jquery

I've written out a very basic script to add/remove a class on load or when a window is resized.

I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing this or if it is possible to reduce the lines of code.

Basically I want to be able to alter the styles when the site is viewed on a smaller screen. I thought it would be best to add a new class to the html tag when it went under a certain width...

Anyways here's my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready( function() {
    /* Check width on page load*/
    if ( $(window).width() < 514) {
     $('html').addClass('mobile');
    }
    else {}
 });

 $(window).resize(function() {
    /*If browser resized, check width again */
    if ($(window).width() < 514) {
     $('html').addClass('mobile');
    }
    else {$('html').removeClass('mobile');}
 });
```

Thanks

Gillian

Comment: one of the options is using Media Queries

Answer (score 56):

Well, I know I'm late to the party, but I saw some things like `$(document).ready()` that weren't really necessary.

Try to cache your selectors if you're calling them over and over again, a la `var $window = $(window);` This will help with performance. I use a function expression to encapsulate to I stay out of the global scope but still have access to my `$window` and `$html` cached jQuery selected elements.

```
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $html = $('html');

    $window.resize(function resize(){
        if ($window.width() < 514) {
            return $html.addClass('mobile');
        }

        $html.removeClass('mobile');
    }).trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/1

Probably a little cleaner, little easier to follow:

```
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),
        $html = $('html');

    function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 514) {
            return $html.addClass('mobile');
        }

        $html.removeClass('mobile');
    }

    $window
        .resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rzdGJ/2

Comment: An example of a GOOD ANSWER :)

Comment: probably bet answer here!

Comment: that is a really awesome answer -- thank you so much, Jared!

Comment: Better late than never!  This is a great solution.

Answer (score 16):

Use Media classes

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .class {
    width:800px;

  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .class {
        width:450px;

  }
}
```

Comment: I really like this solution, short 'n simple!

Comment: I can't explain why, I've just never learned to trust `@media` queries.

Comment: but you must have a strong reason to convince yourself otherwise

Answer (score 15):

First of all, DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) your code by using a function:

```
function checkWidth(init)
{
    /*If browser resized, check width again */
    if ($(window).width() < 514) {
        $('html').addClass('mobile');
    }
    else {
        if (!init) {
            $('html').removeClass('mobile');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth(true);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        checkWidth(false);
    });
});
```

Comment: You don't really need the `$(document).ready()` with the `window` object, and anyhow your `checkWidth()` function could go inside where you setup the `$(window).resize()` handler. If you need to call it later out of scope, you can always `$(window).resize()`.

Comment: IMHO, I think you do need `$(document).ready()`, because on Mobile devices, it doesn't work right on the first load. This is just my experience, so take it with a grain of salt!

Answer (score 8):

```
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 514) {
     $('html').addClass('mobile');
    }
    else {$('html').removeClass('mobile');}
}

$(document).ready( function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

Comment: For some reason, this is the only one that worked really well for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You Can also Use this  Method I think its very clear to follow :

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this);
      if (win.width() < 514) { 

      $('html').addClass('mobile');

      }
    else
    {
        $('html').removeClass('mobile');
    }

});
```

[Simple Method](http://jsfiddle.net/rzdGJ/231/)

Comment: Should be noted that this will only add a class on resize, not on initial page load

Answer (score 2):

This issue pestered me for a while, actually.  I usually have multiple sizes for transitions.  I wrote this an thought I'd share:

```
$(function() {
  var pageTransitions = [['full',1600],['mobile',800],['tiny',400],['micro',0]]; // number shows minimum size - must be from high to low
  function resize() {
    var target = 0,
        w = $(window).width(),
        h = $('html');
    $.each(pageTransitions, function(index, pageTransition) {
        if( w > pageTransition[1]) {
            target = index;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $.each(pageTransitions, function(index, pageTransition) {
        h.removeClass(pageTransition[0]);
    });
    h.addClass(pageTransitions[target][0]);
  }
  resize();
  jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {
    resize();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/ERZ3q/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me

```
function resize() {
        if ($(window).width() < 514) {}
        else {}
    }

    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(window).resize(resize);
        resize();
    });
```