# Jquery, Remove class when width screen is 1050px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is the JS code i'm using:

```
$("document").ready(function($){
var nav = $('#menu2');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 90) {
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }
});
```

But i can't seem to get this into my code.

```
function checkWidth(init){
/*If browser resized, check width again */
if ($(window).width() < 514) {
    $('html').addClass('mobile');
}
else {
    if (!init) {
        $('html').removeClass('mobile');
    }}}$(document).ready(function() {
checkWidth(true);

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth(false);
});
```

And what i want is that when `.f-nav` is added to `#menu2`, when the screen is `<1050` the classshould be removed.

Comment: It seems simpler to use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: well the person that i'm building the site for doesn't want media queries at all. i already said that it is easier, but  he just wants a very clean not extra's simple css. PS sorry for my English i'm Dutch and i'm trying.

Comment: So he's comfortable trading simple, easy to understand CSS for overly complex and unnecessary JavaScript to avoid using one relatively new feature? I don't see the benefit there, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: this is where you should push back and telling him that CSS media queries are cleaner than using javascript

Comment: What's wrong with the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/a/11047637/1741542 ?

Comment: yeah but that's the point a cannot find my answer this is what i want

Comment: ok this is what i want http://jsfiddle.net/39dWe/

Comment: Duplication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472801/different-than-jquery-remove-class-when-width-screen-is-1050px

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To change `html` to `#menu2`, just replace one with the other. jQuery is pretty simple in this respect

```js
if ($(window).width() < 514) {
    $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
} else {
    $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav');
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SM9u/)

Comment: THANK YOU. That's exactually what i wanted.

Comment: Is you know this could you help me with one other little problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do that:

## **Javascript only**

See it in action: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7qAtz/3/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1050) {
        $selector.removeClass('my-class');
    } else {
        $selector.addClass('my-class');
    }
}).resize(); // trigger resize event initially
```

And don't forget: You don't have to place `$(window).resize` inside `$(document).ready`.

## **Mixed Javascript & CSS**

See it in action: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZ3TM/)

This technique is explained here: http://www.senaeh.de/media-query-variablen-javascript-auslesen/

Basic principle: set a variable with a CSS pseudo element and get it with javascript.

This workaround is good if you have to use Javascript even if media queries are used, because you don't have to declare the breakpoint twice.

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    body:after {
        content: 'tablet';
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var mode = window.getComputedStyle(document.body,':after').getPropertyValue('content');
```

Be aware: IE < 9 doesn't support `getComputedStyle`. You have to use a polyfill [like this one](http://snipplr.com/view/13523/).

Comment: Tried this out but turns out it **only** worked when I placed `$(window).resize` within `$(document).ready`. Could you please revisit or update the answer here?

Answer (score 3):

this is best achieved with a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

```
@media screen and (max-width:1050px){
  .mobile{
     /* will only apply on devices narrower than 1050px */
  }
}
```

EDIT: also possible to use media queries with javascript in modern browsers

```
if (matchMedia) {  // check if browser supports media queries from JavaScript
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1050px)");
    WidthChange(mq);
    // every time width changes, check the media query
    mq.addListener(function WidthChange(mq){
       if(mq.matches){
           //we are in a mobile size browser
           $('#menu2').addClass('mobile');
           $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav');
       } else{
           // desktop browser
           $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
           $('#menu2').removeClass('mobile');
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: i know that, but i have to do it with **Javascript**. I know how to **add and remove a class with javascript**. but i want **to link that to when my screen reaches 1050px**, that when it is **1050px** the class will be removed.

Comment: heres one niteresting way to do it, you can use media queries within your js, I believe it's only supported in modern browsers though http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

When you load a website on a screen bigger than your breakpoint, the script wont work, because you need to re-calculate the screen size(refresh the page in this case). You need to get the width of the screen on resize. Use resize() method, and inside it place your test condition, and assign the class to your element. Reference to help you: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: And how am i able to link the resize to the removeclass? i'm sort off a newby in javascript. i know the basic stuff but when it comes to linking to each other i'm breaking javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the class of a div in JS, you can do something like that:

```
document.getElementById("#YourId").className = "YourNewClass"
```

It will just change your class attribute :-)

Like that, you can also check which class is used and do what you want to do with that.

Edit thanks to Olaf Dietsche: this must be a duplicated post, here can be your answer: [jquery, add/remove class when window width changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes/11047637#11047637)

Comment: Yes that i know. but i want to link it to: **function checkWidth(init){
/*If browser resized, check width again */
if ($(window).width() < 514) {
    $('html').addClass('mobile');
}
else {
    if (!init) {
        $('html').removeClass('mobile');
    }}}$(document).ready(function() {
checkWidth(true);

$(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth(false);
});**

Comment: Oh ok, my bad !

Like Olaf Dietsche said, you can check this post which is similar to yours:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes/11047637#11047637