# Different from Jquery, Remove class when width screen is 1050px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coding-style

OK i know now how to remove  abd add class with the width of the window.

But now i'm struggling with this issue:

I want this:

```
 var num = 90; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
    } else {
        $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav');
    }
});
```

to work with this:

```
function checkWidth() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1049) {
        $('#menu2').addClass('f-nav');
    } else {
        $('#menu2').removeClass('f-nav');
    }
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

So in other words,

When i scrolldown it must add a class, but when it resizes it must remove the class + it also has to be removed when i scroll up.

Comment: Why don't you use `@media screen and (min-width: 1049px) {...}` to set the styles for the screen width?

Comment: cause it struggles with my code.

i can't explain why but i really want this to work together

Comment: I have a desktop menu that has to follow when scrolled down but i downt want my responsive menu that is the same coding as desktop menu to also follow to the bottom. that's why i want this to work. and i'm struggling with this the entire week.

Comment: CSS Media queries should do the trick. If you want to seperate the class why not using id of given menu? like #xyz .f-nav and #zyx .f-nav for different menu. In that case you can set fixed to only one of them.

Comment: Thats the problem my desktop and responsive are in the same div #menu2

Comment: From what you're describing it's hard to understand why media queries won't work. The f-nav class can do different things based on the screen width (for example, you could apply position:fixed only when the screen width is over 1050px.)

Comment: Yes but it also has to work when scrolled down to 90px. but when i'm scrolled down at 90px ant makeing the screen smaller than 1050px there have to be no classes added anywhere cause that is the mobile

Comment: Use Javascript to add and remove the class at the 90px scroll position. Then use the media query to change what the class does based on the width. Is there some other reason, besides styling, why that class must not be applied on mobile? Just trying to understand the problem fully.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery, Remove class when width screen is 1050px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469816/jquery-remove-class-when-width-screen-is-1050px)

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment @Lashus's answer

```
|      | > 1050px | < 1050px |
+----------------------------+
| top  | -        | -        |
| down | + f-nav  | - f-nav  |
```

This means, do nothing at the top, but add or remove `f-nav`, when scrolled down

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num)
        checkWidth();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SM9u/2/)

Also note the comment for [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) vs. `.on()`

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: And yes that's exactually what i want

Comment: |      | > 1050px | < 1050px |
+----------------------------+
| top  | -        | -        |
| down | + f-nav  | - f-nav  |

Comment: I modified the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SM9u/2/), it still had the old value of `514px`. If it doesn't work, try making the output frame smaller.

Comment: You my friend are a genius.

Comment: What do mean with that? Is this a cut and paste problem? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a class without using javascript in that case. However you can use CSS Media queries to change the behaviour of given class on different devices.

Example below:

```
(CSS)
.f-nav {
    color: #fff;
}

@media screen AND (max-width: 1050px) {
    .f-nav {
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well i want this:  when i am at the top and screen is bigger than 1050px  f-nav is not added but when i am scrolled down and screen is bigger than 1050px it has to bee added. and when the screen is scrolled down en made smaller than 1050px is has to be removed. but wjhen screen is at top and made smaller than 1050px nothing will be removed cause nothing is added.