# Change (Add/Remove) CSS Class On Mobile With JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I change `ten` on desktop to `three` on mobile with JS or jQuery or SemanticUI?

```html
<div class="ui ten column grid">...</div>
```

If screen size is less than `700px`, change `ten` to `three`.

Comment: If you are okay with a non-JS solution - you can check out [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). They can address this scenario easily without having to change the `class`.

Comment: This is duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469816/jquery-remove-class-when-width-screen-is-1050px

Comment: @SoubhikMondal grid column css (one to ten) is from semanticui, there are defined css codes for "ten" and "three"? which is better: adding js to change class or duplicating same css for @media? It seems more advantageous to change it with JS according to my need now. Thanks all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery, Remove class when width screen is 1050px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469816/jquery-remove-class-when-width-screen-is-1050px)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `$(window).width() < 700` and check if width < 700 then `removeClass` ten and `addClass` three.

This `function` will run even if you `resize` you window manually via `mouse`.

```
//Resize window
function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() < 700) {
    $('.myDiv').removeClass('ten').addClass('three');
  }
}
```

**Runable Example:**

```js
//Resize window
function resize() {
  if ($(window).width() < 700) {
    $('.myDiv').removeClass('ten').addClass('three');
  }
}

//watch window resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  resize()
});
```

```css
.ten {
  background: green;
}

.three {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui ten column grid myDiv">My Div</div>
```

Comment: thanks. how can i select exact div? div.ui.ten.column.grid didn't work.

Comment: `$('div.ui.ten.column.grid')` => It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsLzf2ru/ - are sure you are selecting the right `div` and classes you have originally in your HTML

Comment: it looks correct but where is the problem https://jsfiddle.net/tosunkaya/9tqw1xg7/6/

Comment: Somehow it checks class ORDER. For example when class is "ui ten column grid", after JS add/remove "ten" class and add "three" class, new class is "ui column grid three" which is wrong of order (semanticui checks the order or gives priority). so i removed "ten column grid" and added "three column grid"

i did this and now works. https://jsfiddle.net/tosunkaya/9tqw1xg7/13/

Comment: @emretosunkaya Ahh that make sense. i think its the way semanticUI works. But Glad to hear that - its all good now :) let me know if i can help any further- no problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try this code for JQuery:

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
$("...").removeClass("ten");
$("...").addClass("three");
} else {
$("...").removeClass("three");
$("...").addClass("ten");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this example

```
if ( window.innerWidth < 700 ) {
    document.querySelector("div").classList.add('three');
    document.querySelector("div").classList.remove('ten');
}
```

Comment: this is working , easy and without jquery