# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-bottom on desktop and navbar-static-top on mobile?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, semantic-markup

Is there a way to keep the Bootstrap Navbar be `navbar-fixed-bottom` when it's on mobile, and `navbar-static-top` when on desktop? I was thinking of creating two navbars and hiding one and showing the other, though I'm not sure if that's fine; on a related note, is it alright to use two nav elements with the same role?

Comment: This is possible, yes, you have to use some mediaqueries on this, but it is possible. Your alternative note is that you can have multiple nav elements, and its supported by w3.org for having multiple `navigation` roles on the same page. http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_HTML5_nav_element#Example%3aThe_.3Cnav.3E_element

Comment: @Dorvalla Ah, thank you. So are there aren't any methods of achieving this already built into Bootstrap?

Comment: I cant confirm this, but adding/removing classes by javascript is a solution when it checks for the width of the screen.

Comment: Using jquery you can add or remove classes(for eg: navbar-staic-top and navbar-fixed-bottom). This way you can use the same navbar. No need to hide anything.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes 
This is the perfect solution.

Comment: Is any site available for refence where i can download this type of templates ready for ecommerce website??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this by adding and removing the class of the navbar using javascript jquery according screen width.

```
if ($(window).width() > 330) {
 $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-static-top');
}
else
{
 $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
}
```

It will work for sure

Comment: That will only work on page load, will break if JS is disabled and might cause a flicker of the nav from its starting position on page load. The goal of bootstrap is to be responsive. CSS media queries would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use media queries:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

@media (max-width:767px) { .navbar-static-top { position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; margin: 0; } }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me, and should be easy to understand.

```
var win = $(this);      // browser window
var nav = $('.navbar'); // your navigation bar

function switchNavbar() {
    if (win.width() < 768) { // on mobile
        nav.removeClass('navbar-static-top');
        nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
    } else { // on desktop
        nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-bottom');
        nav.addClass('navbar-static-top');
    }
}

// On first load
$(function() {
    switchNavbar();
});

// When browser resized
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    switchNavbar();
});
```