# Add/Remove CSS id based on screen width

Tags: javascript, css, class, responsive-design

Have been trying to get `$("#id1").add();` and `$("#id2").remove();` to work inside the following function taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes) post. I am getting the `$("#id2").remove();` to work from the console and I would like to get them both to work from inside this function as well.

```
(function($) {
    var $window = $(window),

    function resize() {
        if ($window.width() < 801) {
                $("#id1").add();       
                $("#id2").remove();       
    }
        else {
                $("#id2").add();       
                $("#id1").remove(); 
        }
    }

    $window
        .resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Alternately, is could get it to work using .addClass/.removeClass, but then it has to target all sub classes as well..

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? `add()` and `remove()` are two completely different, pretty much unrelated functions

Comment: This sounds like a job for media queries.

Comment: Well, basically I don't want #id1 and #id2 to be present at a the same time. Media query does not remove the id div from the DOM by using display:none; as I have tested.. is there another way using media query?

Comment: so then, it seems like, you dont ever want to "add" anything, just start the page with both present, then depending on the situation remove the one you want. `remove()` is doing what you think it is, but `add()` serves a different purpose

Comment: Correct! But I will have to re-add the ID's that is removed if the page is re sized.. what can I use for re-adding?

Answer (score 1):

Media queries can be used to toggle the elements' visibility:

**CSS**

```
/* show id1, hide id2, when screen resolution is 800px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #id1 {
        display:block; /*or inline, or whatever */
    }
    #id2 {
        display:none;
    }
}

/* show id2, hide id1, when screen resolution is greater than 800px */
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    #id1 {
        display:none;
    }
    #id2 {
        display:block; /*or inline, or whatever */

    }
}
```

But if they *need* to actually be added and removed from the DOM, then how about this

```
(function($) {
    var $id1=$('#id1');
    var $id1Parent=$id1.parent();
    var $id2==$('#id2');
    var $id2Parent=$id2.parent();

    var $window = $(window),

    function resize() {
                $('#id1,#id2').remove();
        if ($window.width() < 801) {
                $id1Parent.append($id1);
    }
        else {
                $id2Parent.append($id2);
        }
    }

    $window
        .resize(resize)
        .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't think this will remove the #id's from the DOM, just hide them! I need them gone the same way as if I use `$("#idX").remove();`

Answer (score 0):

display none is the way to go for these kind of situations.

The other way is to use JQuery but it will be quite messy if your code gets longer. Or you might want to use AJAX for loading the div part if the div codes are really long.

```
function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 801) {
            $("<div id='1'></div>").appendTo('.container'); //add it to your container       
            $("#id2").remove();       
    }
   else ......
}
```