# Dynamically Changing Class on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, addclass, toggleclass

What I'm doing and have spent many hours attempting today is add a class to an element when the window is resized using the value of the viewport.

Basically, I want to add the class as the viewport value in `<html>` on page load, then change that class as it is resized.

1. Page load - add value of viewport as a class to `<html>`
2. Window resize - change the class added to `<html>` as the viewport value

Right now I have the first part down and I have the second almost there. It will add the viewport value as a class, then when resized add the new value - but it is just adding never ending new classes and not swapping them out.

**Modified code**

omitted `var $html = $("html");`

```
    if(typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined'){
        viewportwidth=window.innerWidth
    }

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){

        var viewportwidth;

            if(typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined'){
                viewportwidth=window.innerWidth;
            }

        jQuery("html").toggleClass(""+viewportwidth);

    });

    jQuery("html").addClass(""+viewportwidth);
```

I'm not very experienced with jQuery and JS...

Example - http://sandbox.iemajen.com/

Thanks.

> Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question.

Let me try to explain more clearly. I would like to have the current value of `window.innerWidth` returned as the only class. That is, when the window is resized, the class cycles to the next value replacing the former.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DLuD.gif)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery, add/remove class when window width changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes)

Comment: How can I count the number of instances of `.addClass(""+viewportwidth);` and keep the oldest / last while removing the previous?

Answer (score 2):

Try this Answer

```
//OnLoad:
$(document).ready(function(){
    w_w = $(window).width();
    if(w_w > some_value){
        $("#some_id").addClass('someClass');
    }
    //onResize
    $(window).resize(function(){
    w_w = $(window).width();
    if(w_w > some_value){
        $("#some_id").addClass('someClass');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var viewportwidth;

        if(typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined'){
              viewportwidth=window.innerWidth;
        }

        if(viewportwidth >= 768){
           $html.addClass("res_768");
        }else{
           $html.removeClass("res_768");
        }

        if(viewportwidth >= 640){
           $html.addClass("res_640");
        }else{
           $html.removeClass("res_640");
        }

        //etc...
});
```

or

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        var viewportwidth;

        if(typeof window.innerWidth!='undefined'){
              viewportwidth=window.innerWidth;
        }

       $html.removeClass();//remove all classes

       if(viewportwidth >= 768){
           $html.addClass("res_768");
       }
       else if(viewportwidth >= 640){
           $html.addClass("res_640");
        }

        //etc...
 });
```