# Bootstrap Carousel: How to stop auto sliding on large screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to find a way to make my slide/carousel to stop when the screen reaches 992px or plus (but it is also nice if it back to work again if I manually reduce my screen size even if the user normally doesn't do it).

So, I tried the code below but it is not working, and doing many researches I just find solutions that disable the auto slide from every size of screen.

Do you have any suggestion?

```
function(){

    var windowIsLarge = window.matchMedia("(min-width:992px)").matches;

    if (windowIsLarge) {
        //carousel disabled
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: false;
        });
    };
};
```

Heres's my updated code, which doesn't work either. I can't see what is wrong with my code there.

```
 $(document).ready(updateCarousel);

 $(window).resize(updateCarousel);


function updateCarousel() {
    var $containerWidth = $(document).width();
    if ($containerWidth <= 998) {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 500
        });
    }
    if ($containerWidth > 998) {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: false
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes) which I think relates, try:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this);
      if (win.width() > 992) { 

      $('carousel').removeClass('carousel');

      }

});
```

Comment: Hi! I'm not really sure if this logic will work, because if I remove the class "carousel" from a div that has the class "carousel", I won't be able to re-put the class if the user resize the window again. But it gives me the idea of applying this change in an ID instead, can be possible, Ill gonna try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're sort of on the right track, but you need to add an event listener to your matchMedia so that it updates as the window resizes.

From: https://www.redweb.com/agency/blog/2013/september/responsive-performance-matchmedia

```
var media = window.matchMedia('(min-width:992px)');
media.addListener(function (mediaQueryList) {
  if (mediaQueryList.matches) {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false
    });
  } else {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 500
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: It looks a pretty good logic, but for some reason it didnt work, I tried to took of the ";" after the false, but it didnt work as well..

Comment: oh yeah, that shouldn't be there. There may be a special bootstrap method for updating such properties post initialization of the carousel.

Comment: The conditions are working perfectly like this:

if ($containerWidth <= 998) {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 500
        });
    }
    if ($containerWidth > 998) {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000
        });
    }

However, they are not being triggered when I change the window width.

Comment: Here is a codepen someone made showing how it updates on change of the window width. I'm going to update my answer to reflect what they have. https://codepen.io/mattdsteele/pen/FmLva

Comment: Thank you, I am going to test your suggestion. I also edited my answer with a more complete code, however it is not working yet

Comment: you should try and make a codepen or jsfiddle, then we could see your code fully and even make changes.

Answer (score 0):

**update:**

```
  if( $(window).width() > 992 ) {
    // disable carousel
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: false,
    });
  }
```

Comment: It should work but is not working, the major problem is the trigger

Comment: Maybe try `$(".carousel").carousel('pause');`

Comment: See the update, I've tested on FF and Chrome, you just need to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

use

`datainterval = "false"` in div tag

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" >
```