# Dynamically change class/property based on window resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the class (or a CSS property of an element) whenever the window size changes using `$(window).resize(function()`

A more simple version of what I'm trying to do can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/cL39emgz/

I'm trying to make the text colour of the element with `id="width"` turn blue every time the width is less than 500px, and turn red every time it is more (or equal to).

So when I resize the screen changing the width, the text should change between blue/red depending on the screen size.

Thanks

Comment: your fiddle has a console error.... `Uncaught ReferenceError: $width is not defined`.  Perhaps that would be a place to start troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: ...Why not use media queries instead? This really does sound like an XY problem.

Comment: here the solution http://jsfiddle.net/cL39emgz/4/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery, add/remove class when window width changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You were close but miss a few things.

You need to change your if statement to the value of the windows `width` as you where changing the span tag

Also for classes use `classList` with add and remove

Hope this helps :)

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#width").text($(this).width());
    $("#height").text($(this).height());
  document.getElementById("width").classList.remove("blue"); 
  document.getElementById("width").classList.remove("red");

    if($(this).width() < 500){
     document.getElementById("width").classList.add("blue");
    }
    else{
     document.getElementById("width").classList.add("red");
    }
});
```

```css
.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Width: <span id="width"></span><br>
Height <span id="height"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this fits what you're trying to do, but you could simply use `window.innerWidth()` and `onresize`

HTML:

```
<body onload="myFunction()" onresize="myFunction()">
    <div id="myDiv">
        Some text
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var width = window.innerWidth();
    if (width <= 500) {
        div.style.color = "blue";
    } else {
        div.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```