# Blog layout shrinks [css]

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

In resolution between 600 px and 1200 px the blog layout terribly shrinks. Post items should arrange next to each other and later one by one. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When your page shrinks the div containing the blog has been given a width of only 93px.

```
<div class="blog_holder massonary isotope" style="***width: 93px;*** position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 8058px; opacity: 1;">
```

Once you have fixed this you will also then need to tell the article elements to be 100% width from their original size of:

```
.blog_holder.massonary article {
    width: 31.5%; > width:100%;
}
```

when the page reaches the width where you want them to be 100%. you will need to use a media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: #px) { }
```

Comment: Yes I know, I have also noticed what you are writing about before. The problem is that these values are generated dynamically. I've now set the width to 100%. It looks better, but there is now a large vertical gap between the posts. The height is also dynamically generated. Can it be controlled, to reduce this gap?

Comment: let me take another look, see what i can figure out

Comment: im not seeing a large vertical gap. Did you fix that already then?

Comment: Hm.. no, it is still visible. If you move the window width smoothly, the height is adjusted accordingly. However, if you open, for example, 800 px wide or you refresh it, the gaps are large.

Comment: oh yes i see it now. Can you post the code that is dynamically giving the html css? it would make it easier to solve!

Comment: sorry i dont mean the template code, i mean the code that is adding the css dynamically, i assume you probably used javascript or jQuery? some type of .js file?

Comment: What im thinking is that the code that is applying the CSS to set the height of the <div class="blog_holder massonary isotope"> section is only adding it when the browser window is resized, so when you load up the blog when its already a small size the code isnt triggered until the window has changed size. maybe a alteration to your script that handles this is all thats needed. see this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047514/jquery-add-remove-class-when-window-width-changes